# Flagging NaN values based on a condition and year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to get this requirement of flagging NaN values based on condition and particular year, below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s={'Fruits':['Apple','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'],'month':['201401','201502','201603','201604'],'weight':[2,4,1,6],'Quant':[251,178,298,300]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
upper = 250
```

How would I be able to flag NaN values for month- `201603` and `201604` (03 and 04 are the months), if `upper>250`. Basically my intention is to check if `Quant` value is greater than defined `upper` value, but for specific date i.e. 201603 and 201604.

This is how the output should look like-

```
Fruits  month   weight  Quant
0   Apple   201401  2   251.0
1   Orange  201502  4   178.0
2   Banana  201603  1   NaN
3   Mango   201604  6   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc`:

```
p.loc[(p.Quant > upper) & (p.month.str[-2:].isin(['03','04'])), 'Quant'] = np.nan
```

OutPut:

```
   Fruits   month  weight  Quant
0   Apple  201401       2  251.0
1  Orange  201502       4  178.0
2  Banana  201603       1    NaN
3   Mango  201604       6    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build a boolean condition that checks if "Quant" is greater than "upper" and the month is "03" or "04", and `mask` "Quant" column:

```
p['Quant'] = p['Quant'].mask(p['Quant'].gt(upper) & p['month'].str[-2:].isin(['03','04']))
```

Output:

```
   Fruits   month  weight  Quant
0   Apple  201401       2  251.0
1  Orange  201502       4  178.0
2  Banana  201603       1    NaN
3   Mango  201604       6    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
p['Quant1'] = p[~(((p['month']=='201603')|(p['month']=='201604'))&(p['Quant']>250))]['Quant']
```

Comment: its creating an extra column `Quant1`